# Read wav data chunk to an array using Naudio

Tags: wav, naudio

I want to read a WAV file using Naudio libraries and save the data chunk info to an array or a string. Please let me know how I can do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WaveFileReader` class. The `Read` method only returns data from the data chunk. If you use the length property, you can assign an array of the correct size and read it in one hit.